# When a new pivot point is found, how can i compare the value with the previous one?

Tags: pine-script-v5

If a pivothigh is calculated using "ta.pviothigh" in pinescript_v5

Can we use pH[1] to indicate the previous pivot high or how can I get the value of the previous one when a new pivot high is found? As I want to check whether the close price of the new found pivot high is higher or lower than the previous pivot high.

I tried the script below and ran it:

pH = ta.pivothigh (close, 5, 5)
pH_fall = pH < pH[1]

plotshape (pH, "pH", shape.triangledown, color=color.aqua, size=size.tiny)
plotshape (pH_fall, "fall", shape.xcross, color=color.black, size=size.small)

It didn't say there is any mistake in the script but it just not showing the black Xcross that should be indicating a falling pivothigh. How should I amend it?